# animation jquery, move right to left

Tags: jquery

I need animate div from right to left on click button

```
   $('#left').click(function() {    
      $("#slideshow").animate({"left":"-300px"}, "slow");           
   });

   <div id="left" class="button">
     <img src="button.png" alt"">
   </div>
```

Comment: ok.. what is your problem..?

Comment: wrap it in document.ready and check if you have included jquery

Comment: show us the complete code. you used some slideshow id.

Comment: $( document ).ready(function() {

  $('#left').click(function() {
   
   $("#slideshow").animate({"left":"-300px"}, "slow");
      
   });
});

Comment: document ready is function

Comment: have you included the jquery lib , if included then check if its loaded properly or not .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a **[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/shaun1ak/7m6MR/)**

```
$('#left').click(function() {
    $("#slideshow").animate({"marginLeft":"-=30px"}, "slow");
});
```

or

```
$('#left').click(function() {
    $("#slideshow").animate({"left":"-=30px"}, "slow");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/JR5B2/1/)... click that left button

```
$('#clc').click(function() {  
  $("#left").animate({"left": "+=50px"}, "slow");
});
```

Comment: $("#slideshow").css({"left":"+=600px"}); is this possible?

Comment: If you use css it just add this left attribute to your #slideshow css .. but animate will slowly change the current value(0) to specified value(600) ... gradually increase .... CV..SV/Duration... for better understanding i have created demo for you http://jsfiddle.net/bB6eT/22/